# Reading values from dynamically created Qlineedit boxes using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyqt

I am creating dynamic labels and line edit boxes based on the number of fields in the shapefile and populating the lineedit boxes using the feature attributes using the below code. Each lineedit box has the field name as object name.

I need to know how to read the current value of each dynamically created lineedit boxes.

```
    def addLayerNames(self):
     for i in reversed(range(self.dlg.verticalLayout.count())):
        self.dlg.verticalLayout.itemAt(i).widget().setParent(None)
     layers = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values()
     layer_list = []
     for layer in layers:
        if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer:
            layer_list.append(layer.name())
     self.dlg.comboBox.addItems(layer_list)
     selectedLayerIndex = self.dlg.comboBox.currentIndex()
     selectedLayer = layers[selectedLayerIndex]
     fields = selectedLayer.pendingFields()
     fieldnames = [field.name() for field in fields]
     for i,field in enumerate(fieldnames):
        self.labels = QLabel()
        self.linedit = QLineEdit()
        self.labels.setText(field)
        self.linedit.setFixedWidth(100)
        self.dlg.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.labels)
        self.dlg.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.linedit)
        request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFid(0)
        layer.setSelectedFeatures([0])
        self.iface.actionZoomToSelected().trigger()
        feat = layer.getFeatures(request).next()
        self.linedit.setText(str(feat[i]))
        self.linedit.setObjectName(field)
        self.dlg.pushButton.setEnabled(False)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example can be reduced to

```
for i, field in enumerate(fieldnames):
    self.lineedit = QLineEdit()
    self.lineedit.setText(str(feat[i]))
```

Each new `QLineEdit` is assigned to the same variable `self.lineedit`. Each time a new lineedit is created, the reference to the old one is lost.

One solution to overcome this problem is to save them in a `list`

```
self.lineedits = list()
for i, field in enumerate(fieldnames):
    lineedit = QLineEdit()
    lineedit.setText(str(feat[i]))
    self.lineedits.append(lineedit)
```

**Note:** This is a generic programming question, unrelated to PyQGIS